# Chromium android Build invalid option --jarjar

Tags: java, android, python, chromium

ninja build is adding invalid option --jarjar. any pointer how to fix this.

Here are the error details:

```
cd ../../ui/gfx; ../../base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator.py --input_file "../android/java/src/org/chromium/ui/gfx/ViewConfigurationHelper.java" --output_dir ../../out/Release/gen/ui/gfx/jni --includes base/android/jni_generator/jni_generator_helper.h --optimize_generation 1 --jarjar "" --ptr_type long --native_exports_optional
```

Usage: jni_generator.py [OPTIONS]
This script will parse the given java source code extracting the native
declarations and print the header file to stdout (or a file).
See SampleForTests.java for more details.

```
jni_generator.py: error: no such option: --jarjar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'--jarjar' option is not supported since: https://codereview.chromium.org/1959583003

Until gyp files are properly cleaned you can remove the option from build/jni_generator.gypi (generate_jni_headers) and re-generate files with gyp_chromium.

```
diff --git a/build/jni_generator.gypi b/build/jni_generator.gypi
index 7a9e333..da6e380 100644
--- a/build/jni_generator.gypi
+++ b/build/jni_generator.gypi
@@ -58,8 +58,6 @@
         '<(jni_generator_includes)',
         '--optimize_generation',
         '<(optimize_jni_generation)',
-        '--jarjar',
-        '<(jni_generator_jarjar_file)',
         '--ptr_type',
         '<(jni_generator_ptr_type)',
         '<(native_exports)',
```